# Why do I have to also SELECT an aggregate column to be able to use GROUP BY, if the only SELECTed column is already in GROUP BY?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

In the data used by the formula below, column C contains a list of product titles (these are not unique, and many are blank); column Q contains the category for each product, and column F contains that product's sales. If possible, I'd like to avoid posting any actual data (as it belongs to my employer), but I can mock up some bogus rows in the identical format if it's deemed necessary.

What I want to do is to produce a list of the non-blank product titles in a certain category with the highest aggregate sales, sorted in descending order, limited to 25 entries.

The following formula seems to me to be perfectly legitimate:

```
=QUERY('Raw Data'!A:Q, "Select C where Q = 'foo' and C != '' group by C order by sum(F) desc limit 25", 1)
```

But it isn't. I get the error "CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG". I've found that to make this work, I need to select sum(F) as well, like so:

```
=QUERY('Raw Data'!A:Q, "Select C, sum(F) where Q = 'foo' and C != '' group by C order by sum(F) desc limit 25", 1)
```

First of all, why is this? The documentation (found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#group-by)) states that "If you use a group by clause, then every column listed in the select clause must either be listed in the group by clause, or be wrapped by an aggregation function." I don't see how the first formula doesn't obey this criterion; every column in select (i.e. only C) is listed in the group by clause.

Second of all, how can I best modify this formula (if I can at all) to be able to only select C? If I'm not doing anything wrong (doubtful, but possible), is there a workaround for this, or do I have to just deal with it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665885/why-do-i-have-to-provide-an-items-id-column-to-the-group-by-clause), and others like it, don't answer my question - I understand that if I want to select multiple columns, as I do in the second formula given above, I need to provide an aggregation function so that it's clear how they are to be grouped. In this case, though, there's only one column - I just want it (and only it) to be grouped. What am I missing here that doesn't allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to wrap another QUERY formula around the first one:

`=QUERY(QUERY('Raw Data'!A:Q, "select C, sum(F) where Q = 'foo' and C != '' group by C order by sum(F) desc limit 25", 1),"select Col1")`

Answer (score 1):

What I've ended up doing in practice is wrapping the 2-column response in `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN()`, like so:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY('Raw Data'!A:Q, "Select C, sum(F) where Q = 'foo' and C != '' group by C order by sum(F) desc limit 25", 1), 1, 10000)`

`10000` is used for the number of columns as being something arbitrarily large, larger than what I know the `QUERY()` should output. This seems to be the cheapest solution I can find.